# Moderntimeline.sty not found?

Tags: moderncv

My notebook crushed and I copied my latex files to another pc. I tried to run my file which creates my cv and cover letter, however I get the error message:

> moderntimeline.sty not found

I deinstalled and installed the moderncv package again, but I still get the error message. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have `moderntimeline` installed on your PC? It is a separate package, loaded by `moderncv`.

Comment: ok, see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows and this: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline

Comment: There are a multitude of sources for errors. Your TeX hash database might be corrupted

Comment: See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline